# Optimum way of chaining dependent HTTP GET requests

Tags: typescript, rxjs, angular5, angular-router

I am writing an application in Angular (current v5.1.1) and I have a couple of questions regarding the following scenario:
I have a list of doctors displayed in a datatable. When the user clicks on any row, I am saving the selected doctor's details in an injectable service and then redirect (using the angular-router) to a new component (page) to display more details. These details include personal details, office locations - can be more than 1 - and working hours per office location.

I do not own the back-end services so I cannot create a service to return all the results through a single call. There is a service that returns all the office locations by providing the doctor's ID and there is another service that returns the working hours for each location by providing the doctor's ID and the office's ID.

What I want to achieve is to render the new component (page) once I have all the data returned by the service calls and not have the data appearing asynchronously e.g. the personal details appearing first since they are in-memory or the office locations appearing one by one. Therefore I have decided to use the router resolve method to achieve this. **Is this the best practice to achieve what I want?**

Now for retrieving the data I need for the new component, I used a combination of RxJS operators and I managed to get the desired outcome using the following code inside the resolve method:

```
this.doctorDetails = this.doctorDetailsService.getDetails();
this.doctorId = this.doctorDetails.uniqueCode;

return  this.doctorsService.getofficeLocations(this.doctorId)
.mergeMap((results: any[]) => {
        return Observable.forkJoin(
            results.map((result: any) => {
                return Observable.forkJoin(
                    Observable.of(result),
                    this.doctorsService.getofficeHours(this.doctorId, result.officeId)
                ).map((data: any[]) => {
                    const officeDetails = data[0];
                    const officeHours = data[1];
                    officeDetails.officeHours = officeHours;
                    return officeDetails;
                });

            })
        );
});
```

**Is there any better way to do this (mostly in terms of performance and code-quality)?**

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better to write all that code, for different reasons.

**Reason 1**
In a general way, but especially when working with Rxjs, try to avoid side effects. Embrace functional programming as much as you can.

**Reason 2**
There's no need to use `forkJoin` here:

```
return Observable.forkJoin(
    Observable.of(result),
    this.doctorsService.getofficeHours(this.doctorId, result.officeId)
).map(...)
```

To avoid that kind of "mistake" you should always ask yourself if you need to wrap a value into an observable if you're extracting that exact same value right after.

**Reason 3**
Nobody wants to read... Unreadable code. Try to split your code into smaller functions (which will help you to read your own code but also to test it).

**Proposal:**

```
public getDetailsAndHours(doctorId: string) {
  return this.doctorsService
    .getofficeLocations(doctorId)
    .switchMap((results: any[]) => this.getDetailsAndHoursForAll(results));
}

private getDetailsAndHoursForAll(results: any[], doctorId: string) {
  return Observable.forkJoin(
    ...results.map(result =>
      this.getDetailsAndHoursForADoctorAndService(
        doctorId,
        result.officeId
      )
    )
  )
}

private getDetailsAndHoursForADoctorAndService(doctorId: string, officeId: string) {
  return this.doctorsService
    .getofficeHours(doctorId, officeId)
    .map(officeDetailsAndHours => ({
      ...officeDetailsAndHours[0],
      officeHours: officeDetailsAndHours[1]
    }));
}
```

About the resolver, it looks like a good idea to me.